# what does server requirements have (Material) AngulasJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to setup a test server for an AngularJS application (using also nodeJS modules and the actual framework is Angular Material + browserify).

what is the technology stack I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are speaking of [MEAN Stack](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and) acronym for [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/), [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) and [Node](https://nodejs.org/), You can have a taste of up and running from [here](http://mean.io/#!/) and Material Design provides reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components to be used inside AngularJS Apps.

Here is cool sample [Github](https://github.com/zishon89us/mean-stack) and its [Demo](http://mean-io-stack.herokuapp.com/#!/) by me.

Happy Helping!

Comment: so, if Install mean.io on a test server, I should be able to deploy any front-end application (including call to Web services) based on Angular and using Angular Material UI framework. right?

Comment: yes its full stack solution, nodejs is server, angularjs is front-end and material is ui-framework, you are right! you can also deploy it, also can make calls (kinda web services)